# Add a button in the Finder toolbar

Tags: macos, finder

How can I add a button in the Finder toolbar? I don't use the dropdown menu. For example, I want to carry out the first (only the button), not the second (dropdown list menu).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right click > customize toolbar.

[image]

Then drag in or out the buttons you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open a new Finder window (if not already visible) by clicking on the Finder icon in the Dock or by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

Now in the Finder Menu, click on View item and make sure toolbar is visible else select Show Toolbar. Now click on View → Customize Toolbar... item. You will be presented with a screen showing all available toolbar controls.

[image]

Drag and drop the items as desired into the Toolbar.